# Collection is not a function or Collection is not a constructor in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, kendo-ui

This code of mine keeps on throwing error i don't understand why.

```
var id = $(ev.currentTarget).data("id");
    var item = ItemCollection.getByCid(id);
    alert(item.get("ItemCode"));
    var qty = 1;
    var cartcollection = new CartCollection();
    cartcollection.add( item );
    CartListView.render();
    var itemcode = cartcollection.where({ItemCode: item.get("ItemCode")});
    if( itemcode.length > 0 ){ alert("success"); }
```

So what i want to do is check if the CartCollection has the same model already and if true it should update the Qty atrib of the model only. Now based on that code it returns CartCollection is not a function or not a constructor. Why the hell is that!? Any ideas? Thanks

## Update

I'm using backbone,require,KendoUI grid and underscore on this one so my code is this:

itemlist_view.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'model/item_model',
'model/cart_model',
'collection/item_collection',
'collection/cart_collection',
'view/cart/cartlist_view',
'text!templates/items/itemlist.html'
 ],function($, _, Backbone, Item, Cart, ItemCollection, CartCollection, CartListView, ItemListTemplate){

var ItemListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#mainContainer"),
events:{
    "click #itemListContainer li" : "AddToCart"
},
initialize: function(){
  this.model = Item;
  this.collection = ItemCollection;
  this.collection.bind("reset", this.render );
},
render: function(){
  var data = {
    items: ItemCollection.models
  }
  var compiledTemplate = _.template( ItemListTemplate , data);
  $("#itemContainer").html( compiledTemplate );
},
AddToCart:function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var id = $(ev.currentTarget).data("id");
    var item = ItemCollection.getByCid(id);
    alert(item.get("ItemCode"));
    var qty = 1;
    var cartcollection = new CartCollection();
    cartcollection.add( item );
    CartListView.render();
    var itemcode = cartcollection.where({ItemCode: item.get("ItemCode")});
    if( itemcode.length > 0 ){ alert("success"); }
}
});
return new ItemListView;
});
```

cart_collection.js

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone',
'model/cart_model'
],function(_, Backbone, Cart){
var CartCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Cart,
  initialize: function(){

  }
});
return new CartCollection;
 });
```

cartlist_view.js

```
define([
 'jquery',
 'underscore',
 'backbone',
 'model/cart_model',
 'collection/cart_collection',
 'text!templates/cart/cartlist.html'
 ], function($, _, Backbone, Cart, CartCollection, CartListTemplate){

var Model = kendo.data.Model,
    ObservableArray = kendo.data.ObservableArray;

function wrapBackboneModel(backboneModel, fields) {
    return Model.define({
        fields: fields,
        init: function(model) {
            if (!(model instanceof backboneModel)) {
                model = new backboneModel(model);
            }

            Model.fn.init.call(this, model.toJSON());
            this.backbone = model;
        },
        set: function(field, value) {
            Model.fn.set.call(this, field, value);

            this.backbone.set(field, value);
        }
    });
}

function wrapBackboneCollection(model) {
    return ObservableArray.extend( {
        init: function(collection) {
            ObservableArray.fn.init.call(this, collection.models, model);

            this.collection = collection;
        },

        splice: function(index, howMany) {
            var itemsToInsert, removedItemx, idx, length;

            itemsToInsert = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

            removedItems = kendo.data.ObservableArray.fn.splice.apply(this, arguments);

            if (removedItems.length) {
                for (idx = 0, length = removedItems.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                    this.collection.remove(removedItems[idx].backbone);
                }
            }

            if (itemsToInsert.length) {
                for (idx = 0, length = itemsToInsert.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                    this.collection.unshift(itemsToInsert[idx].backbone);
                }
            }

            return removedItems;
        }
    });
}

kendobackboneCollection = wrapBackboneCollection;
kendobackboneModel = wrapBackboneModel;


var CartListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#cartContainer"),

initialize: function(){
  this.collection = CartCollection;
  this.model = Cart;
  this.collection.bind("change", this.render );
},
render: function(){
  console.log("here");
  this.el.html(CartListTemplate);
  var CartWrapper = kendobackboneModel(Cart, {
     ItemCode: { type: "string" },
     ItemDescription: { type: "string" },
     RetailPrice: { type: "string" },
     Qty: { type: "string" },
  });
  var CartCollectionWrapper = kendobackboneCollection(CartWrapper);

  this.$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    editable: true,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: ["ItemDescription", "Qty", "RetailPrice"],
    dataSource: {
      schema: {model: CartWrapper},
      data: new CartCollectionWrapper(CartCollection),
     }
  });
  
},

});
return new CartListView;
});
```

Comment: So what exactly is your error and where does it occur?

Comment: Can you post the code where you create your `CartCollection` constructor function? It sounds like the cause will be in that code. Maybe you aren't creating `CartCollection` before this snippet runs?

Comment: @tkone the error is using this code CartCollection.where(); it says CartCollection is not a function. If i will instantiate it cartcollection = new CartCollection(); then use cartcollection.where() it says CartCollection is not a constructor.

Comment: @silent__thought I updated the codes above. I included the view and the collection just like you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are double instantiating the `CartCollection`. That is, `cart_collection.js` returns a `new CartCollection()` and in `itemlist_view.js` you instantiate it again with `var cartcollection = new CartCollection();`.

Change that line to `var cartcollection = CartCollection;` and see how that does. Obviously you could also remove the `cartcollection` variable and replace its usages with `CartCollection`.

On another note, I would seriously consider NOT returning `new CartCollection()` from your `cart_collection.js`. This feels like a very bad practice in that you will only ever be able use one instance of that collection. Also, it isn't obvious to the developer that they are getting back an instance of the collection rather than the constructor for it.

I would recommend returning `CartCollection` instaed, and then instantiating it in your `itemlist_view.js` file with `new CartCollection()`. This way you will be able to instantiate more of those collections later if needed.

Same recommendation for `cartlist_view.js` returning a `new CartListView()`.

Comment: I marked your answer correct because i have a problem too about the models and your answer is right about my model problem. But for the collection since i have return new CartCollection on my cart_collection.js i should directly use CartCollection on my views. But still CartCollection.where({itemcode : item.get("itemcode")}) problem persists. It still says CartCollection.where is not a function. Would this be a bug? because i can add but the where function doesn't work.

Comment: Ah. It just hit me that collections don't have a `where` function. You are probably wanting the `filter` function instead.

Comment: That's it. But based on the documentation it has a where function. Thanks man. ;)

Comment: just would like to ask based on your suggestion not to return "new" on models and collections. I did it but the question is i can add an item to cartcollection on itemlist_view but when i call render (using breakpoint in firebug) the added data doesn't appear on cartlist_view file.